# Laravel load custom config

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to integrate custom code into my Laravel project, here's the current folder structure :

[image: Screenshot]

You can see my controllers and models - views are in a module subfolder and I already made the controller and views run properly, but now I want to load a config file under `module/Csol/Fight/Config`, named `development.php` (for example) - here's my current attempt :

In my controller :

```
public function __construct() 
{
    $namespacePath = substr(__NAMESPACE__, 0,  strrpos(__NAMESPACE__, "\\"));
    View::addNamespace($namespacePath, app_path()."/module/".str_replace("\\", "/",     $namespacePath).'/views');
    Config::addNamespace($namespacePath, app_path()."/module/".str_replace("\\", "/",     $namespacePath).'/Config');
    var_dump(get_class(Config::getFacadeRoot()));
}

public function showWelcome()
{
    // View::addLocation(app_path().'/module/Csol/Fight/views');
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($this);
    echo "</pre>";
    var_dump(Csol\Fight\Config::getItems());
    die();
    return View::Make("Csol\Fight::a");
}
```

development.php:

```
return array(
    "dbs"=>array(
        "host"=>"sss",
        "db_name"=>"ccc",

    )
);
```

I can't get the result of my own config file, any help please ?

Comment: What's the exact error message ? Also I've edited your question to improve spelling and formatting.

Comment: @André,there have no error message,i just can't get my configuration from /module/Csol/Fight/Config/development.php

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually loading that file.

Comment: @André,i load it like load view template:View::addNamespace($namespacePath, app_path()."/module/".str_replace("\\", "/",     $namespacePath).'/views');
    Config::addNamespace($namespacePath, app_path()."/module/".str_replace("\\", "/",     $namespacePath).'/Config');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed...
takes me a little more time...
I should use this `var_dump(Config::get('Csol\Fight::development.xxx'));`
instead of `var_dump(Csol\Fight\Config::getItems())`;
have fun...